# How to programing mix 32bit lib and 64bit lib

Tags: visual-studio, 32bit-64bit

I'm doing programming with Visual Studio 2013. 
I need to use both 32-bit and 64-bit libs.

How can i use both libs in the same project?
And if it's impossible, what should I do?

I know some approaches:

- use TCP/IP in localhost
- use DDE(Dynamic Data Exchage)

If you have some an idea please tell me.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. You need to use 2 different processes and use inter process communication like localhost networking.

Comment: Thank you for Answer me. ^^ Ok I got it. I will try to TCP/IP.